# Не работает youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0

Tags: java, android, youtube

Получаю null в downloadUrl.

Вот код MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.VideoMeta;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YtFile;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    public String youtubeLink;
    public String downloadUrl;
    private VideoView vv;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       
        // set content view to binding's root
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        vv = findViewById(R.id.videoYT);
        
        youtubeLink = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXX";
        YouTubeUrlVideo(youtubeLink);
        
    }
    
    public void YouTubeUrlVideo(String youtubeLink){
        new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(android.util.SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int itag = 22;
                    downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
                }
            }
       }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
        if(downloadUrl != null){
           vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
        }else{
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                               "error",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Зависимость:

```
dependencies {
implementation("com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v2.1.0")
}
```

Почему возвращает null и как тогда сделать, чтобы всё работало нормально?

Comment: `This repository has been archived by the owner`, ищите другую библиотеку. https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor/issues/243 Но очень сомневаюсь что найдете.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо!